# Phone with removable battery or hardware off?

Tags: smartphones

Long story short, I work with a lot of RF equipment, and it would be really convenient if I could have a phone that I could truly turn *OFF* instead of having to leave it a million miles away in a shield box. So either one with a true hardware off, if such a thing exists, or one with a battery that can easily be removed and put back in. Thank you.

It's OK if it's an older phone, at the end of the day I just need it for calling and texting.

(I found this question, however it's 3 years old: [Android phone with removeable battery, SD Card, USB Host/OTG for ~100 - $150](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1630/android-phone-with-removeable-battery-sd-card-usb-host-otg-for-100-150))

Comment: That might be a 3 year old question, but to be fair, any phone with a removable battery is going to be at least 2-3 years old. Unless you are looking for a feature phone and not a smartphone, then I suppose some might exist. Provide more specifics on what you are looking for.

Comment: Are you saying that modern smartphones send radio signals even when fully turned off or in airplane mode? Or is your stuff sensitive to noise from DC/DCs inside the phone?

Comment: You mean my phone isn't truly off when off? How?

Answer (score 1):

Despite that the majority of models these days have an integrated battery , there still are smartphones that can have their battery easily removed, like [Samsung Galaxy J4](https://klgadgetguy.com/2018/07/22/samsung-galaxy-j4-2018-review-the-free-smartphone-you-will-want-to-own/)

One easy way to discover some phones (but not all) is to use a site which has parametric search like Kimovil. Here's the page to see models with removable battery less than one year old:

[Smartphones with removable battery released last 12 months](https://www.kimovil.com/en/compare-smartphones/f_min_dm+unveileddate.4,fe_battery-removable)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's funny how you tagged your question "smartphones", asking for this functionality.  Practically all non-smartphones will be truly off when you turn off their power.  So get a flip phone; or, if you need more functionality, there's plenty more advanced non-smartphones, such as Samsung Star 2, or a variety of Blackberries.